# How can I recreate this distortion effect from Midsommar?

Tags: video, premiere, after-effects, effects

I want to create a distortion effect around someone's head, kind of like what a swirly bokeh would do.  There are two different shots that I could find that use this effect in the film 'Midsommar', one in which there is a swirly distorted effect around a head, and another where general swirls around the screen appear.  While it looks like a keyframed liquify effect from PhotoShop, I'm not sure if it can be recreated in after effects.  How can I do this?
[image]
https://giphy.com/gifs/a24-midsommar-QW3GavVLEeTa3Rpkx1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having seen the movie, it may be difficult to get it down exactly, but here is what I came up with.

- Duplicate your layer twice, so that you have three copies.
- On the top layer mask out the person.

[image]

- Set the mask feather to around 30px.
- Copy and paste the mask to the other two layers.
- On the middle layer, set the mask feather to 60 and the mask expansion to 60. (can be adjusted to suit).
- On the bottom layer, set the mask to subtract mode and add a 'Turbulent Displace' effect to the layer.
- Adjust the size to suit (I chose 30) and you can keyframe the 'Amount' to have it animate on or off. I also added the expression 'time * 500' to the 'Evolution' property to add some movement.

Here is what mine ended up looking like:

[image]

Hope this is close to what you're after.

Comment: yes!  the keyframing is a bit fast/bouncey but I'm sure I can slow that down.  otherwise this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

This is a desired look that stills photographers have been creating with Helios 44 lenses. It's quite possibly a native analogue effect see swirly bokeh.  To simulate the effect using the above using @clif's three layer solution. On the bottom layer with spherical distortion, radial focus blur, and some circular smearing increasing at the boundary of the image.

Ref:  https://live.staticflickr.com/967/27986297808_2f0f5ebaf2_b.jpg